# How can I use makefile syntax in Android.mk

Tags: android, makefile

I'd like to use **makefile** syntax in Android.mk. Cause I wanna generate a special bin file. But I don't know how to do it. I tried several method, but no one worked. Anybody knows it?
Thanks.

Right now, my implementation is:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
INTERNAL_OBMRES_FILES := $(TOPDIR)frameworks/base/core/res/assets/images/android-logo-mask.png \
    $(TOPDIR)frameworks/base/core/res/assets/images/android-logo-shine.png

LOCAL_MODULE := obmRes.bin
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_REQUIRED_MODULES := $(RGB2565)
BUILT_OBMRES_TARGET := $(PRODUCT_OUT)/obmRes.bin

obmRes.bin:$(BUILT_OBMRES_TARGET)
$(BUILT_OBMRES_TARGET): $(INTERNAL_OBMRES_FILES)
        $(hide) convert $(TOPDIR)frameworks/base/core/res/assets/images/android-logo-mask.png $(TOPDIR)frameworks/base/core/res/assets/images/android-logo-shine.png -compose dstover -size 256x64 -composite -depth 8 rgb:$(PRODUCT_OUT)/temp.bin
        $(hide) $(RGB2565) < $(PRODUCT_OUT)/temp.bin > $@
        $(hide) rm -f $(PRODUCT_OUT)/temp.bin

include $(BUILD_PHONY_PACKAGE)
```

But it don't work.

Comment: Android.mk is not *the* makefile of your JNI build - it's a part of a much bigger makefile. You can use makefile syntax all you want. But the target being built is normally outside of your control. Please tell more about the "special bin file".

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well, I would like to use imageMagic to combine two png file. And output it as a raw file. I want to control it by Android.mk.

Answer (score 0):

You want to combine two PNG's at compile time for your Android project, right? Why do you want to use the NDK for that? Write a program for the host computer (you can use Cygwin and GCC with ImageMagick), run it, then place the generated PNG into the project. No need to do that in NDK.

Makefile in NDK (or any other makefile) is something YOU run, not the user. Whatever is done in makefiles is done before you ship your app.

Now, if you want the user to do the PNG combining, then you don't need a "special bin". You just need a regular NDK project, which produces a library (.SO) which your Android app will call, passing file names as parameters. The app, once you build it and ship it, won't have a makefile in it - just a compiled library.

EDIT from OP's question edit: don't waste time with Android NDK. Just run the relevant commands under Cygwin (or *nix shell).

Comment: It's not for building a android app. My work is release android rom. And the 'special bin' is used to display logo when boot rom run. My purpose is automatically generate this file while building entire android system.

Comment: How often do you need to rebuild that logo? Do you really need to make sure it's up to date on every single build?